# html onsubmit doesn't start Javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a form with a Javascript populated collection of cacheable items, and a text box that is an id that is entered by a user. I want on the form submit to redirect the user to the JSON response from the rest call. The rest URL works when I enter directly into the browser however transferring that to html and js is beating me. The form on submit does nothing when the submit is clicked.

My form -

```
<form id="query" action="get" onsubmit="return restLink();">
  <td>
    <select id="selectCacheableItemType">
      <option>Select a Cacheable Item Type</option>
    </select>
  </td>
  <td>
    Cacheable item Id: <input type="text" id="cacheableId"><br>
  </td>
</form>
```

The cacheable item type is populated here -

```
window.onload = function cacheItemType(){
    var select = document.getElementById("selectCacheableItemType");
    var options = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6","7"];
    for(var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
        var opt = options[i];
        var el = document.createElement("option");
        el.textContent = opt;
        el.value = opt;
        select.appendChild(el);
    }
};
```

and the restLink() function is -

```
function restLink() {   
    cachetypename = document.getElementyId('selectCacheableItemType').getValue();
    cacheid = document.getElementyId('cacheableId').getValue();
    return window.location.href = "http://localhost:8080/rest/query/"+ cachetypename + "/" + cacheid;
}
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Where is the submit button? Your HTML is invalid. You can not have a form around td tags.

Comment: have you tried to add submit input? and make onclick event on that submit input?

Comment: setting `window.location.href` will make you go to that page. Secondly when you have an error in your javascript, your function wont be called/finnished. In browser open your developers tools -> console to see if your javascript returns errors when you submit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to set window.location.href.  You either want to submit the form to this url.  Or you don't need a form at all and just want to change the location to this url.  You are combining 2 things and that is why it isn't working.  I would get rid of the from and just create a button with onclick calling your restLink() method. No need for a form here.

Something like this:

```
<table>
<tr>
  <td>
    <select id="selectCacheableItemType">
      <option>Select a Cacheable Item Type</option>
    </select>
  </td>
  <td>
    Cacheable item Id: <input type="text" id="cacheableId"><br>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <input type="button" id="enterButton" onclick="restLink()">
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This was the answer that worked best for me. Many thanks. Have an up vote and accepted tick.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding a submit button?

```
<form id="query" action="get" onsubmit="return restLink();">
  <td>
    <select id="selectCacheableItemType">
      <option>Select a Cacheable Item Type</option>
    </select>
  </td>
  <td>
    Cacheable item Id: <input type="text" id="cacheableId"><br>
  </td>
 <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submitForm"/>
</form>
```

And then:

```
$(document).ready(
function(){
    cacheItemType();
 var select = $("#selectCacheableItemType");
    var options = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6","7"];
    for(var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
        var opt = options[i];
        var el = document.createElement("option");
        el.textContent = opt;
        el.value = opt;
        select.appendChild(el);
});
```